# Consumir dados de uma tabela já existente no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma base de utilização do Laravel, porém sempre utilizei este criando as tabelas pelas migrations.

Sei consumir dados de um banco em php também, porém neste caso tenho que construir a classe para tal.

Estou tentando fazer um aplicação com Laravel que irá consumir dados de um banco já existente, neste caso qual a maneira correta para que possa utilizar estes dados na aplicação? Crio o migration igual se fosse criar o banco já existente?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não precisa criar a `migration` só o `model`

Essa ferramenta pode te ajudar:
https://blog.especializati.com.br/criar-migrations-no-laravel-a-partir-de-banco-de-dados-existente/

Answer (score 1):

As *migrations* são necessárias se você for criar ou modificar tabelas no bando de dados.

Para manipular estas tabelas, você pode [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries), ou seja, sem a necessidade de um `Model`, por exemplo:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
$user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();
DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->update(['votes' => 1]);
```

Se você precisa do `Model` na sua aplicação, é bom salientar que o `Model` do Laravel tem configurações por padrão, por exemplo, o nome da tabela, qual a coluna é chave primária e se a tabela tem as colunas `created_at` e `updated_at`. Tabelas criadas fora dos padrões são necessários especificar. Na dúvida, olha a documentação do [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent).

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Pessoas extends Model{
    protected $table = 'pessoas';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_pessoa';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```